# pass variables from javascript to php with a cookie

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, cookies

this has been asked before, i want to do it so i can avoid refreshing the page caused by `POST` and `GET`, and ajax seems the right way

but i was wondering if i can make a cookie with javascript and then (from the same page) access it with php. is it possible?

small example:

```
//html code:
<form name="PLForm" onsubmit="myFunction()">
   <input type="text" name="PLName"/>
</form>

//JS part:
myFunciton() {
   var cname = "playlistName";
   var cvalue = document.form["PLForm"]["PLName"];
   document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue;
}

//in php:
<?php
   $x = $_COOKIE["playlistName"];
   //some code
?>
```

Comment: PHP runs BEFORE the page is sent to the client.

Comment: so ajax is the only way?

Comment: If you want something to happen without reloading the page, yes. I think you need to brush up on the relationship between the client, server, PHP, and Javascript. If you understand the data flow, it's should be obvious what's wrong with your code.

Comment: you are right, i see how illogical this is, for php that cookie is not even there...

Comment: `$_COKKIE`? i bet this will throw an undefined variable, because there is no such thing

Comment: there is such thing, it's called $_TYPO